# spurious section breaks in tex4ht's output before lists, block quotes, etc

Tags: floats, tex4ht, latex-to-word

When I use `tex4ht` to convert a `xelatex` document using the `memoir` class to `.odt` (and then convert that to `.docx`), spurious Section Breaks appear throughout the resulting `.docx` file. They appear immediately before:

- lists (enumerated or itemized)
- block quotes
- floats (like figures and tables)

I believe this is a bug. Is there a way to fix it?

## Update with MWE

I realized that this only seems to be a real problem when I use the `endfloat` package to put floats at the end of the document.

Also, I haven't been able to make the minimal version display the same problems with block quotes as I have seen in my longer, more complex documents. But since `tex4ht` is using Section Breaks for them too, maybe that's the problem? It seems to me that a Section Break is unnecessary for a block quote.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[12pt,article,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

% FLOATS / FIGURES at the END
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}
\renewcommand\figureplace{}

% IGNORE FIGURES
\newcommand\includegraphics[1][1]{}
\renewcommand\vspace[1]{}

\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text goes here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


Text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.
\begin{quote}
This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote. This is a long block quote.
\end{quote}
More text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\caption{default}
\label{default}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

New paragraph \textbf{following figure}. More text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%    My text ends here:    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

tex4ht output:

[image]

ditto, with invisible characters showing:

[image]

There should be no gap before the last paragraph.

Comment: In MS Word, the spurious section breaks are labeled "Section Break (Continuous)", in case that helps solve the mystery.

Comment: sections are used for  various styling purposes, I don't think we can get rid of them